# Amazon QuickSight - Display number

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight, quicksight-embedding

I am trying Amazon Quicksight but I don't understand if this is possible.
I should display a number that is calculated:

[(a-b) / c]

a - is chosen from a list of data in the column A
b - is the mean of the column B
c - is the mean of the column C

it's possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Where a differs depending on the row in column A? I don't think this is possible as you are writing a formula using both aggregated fields (mean of b or c) and a non-aggregated field (a).

I tried the formula with both and got the following error (using the [avg function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/avg-function.html)):

> Mismatched aggregation. Custom aggregations can’t contain both
> aggregate "`AVG`" and non-aggregated fields “AVG("ColumnId-2")”, in
> any combination.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

@Occamatic is right about inability to use both aggregated fields and a non-aggregated field in your formula.

However, you can circumvent this by using 'a' in an aggregated function in your calculated field. Example:

```
( sumIf({a},{a}={a}) - b ) / c
```

Please amend to the specifics to your dashboard, possibly with use of [parameters in ifelse statements](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/parameters-calculated-fields.html), but a version of this should work.

For instance, I myself can't use:

```
ifelse({metric_type}='Averages',avg({metric_value}),sum({metric_value}))
```

Instead I use:

```
ifelse(avgIf({metric_value},{metric_type}='Averages') > 0,avg({metric_value}),sum({metric_value}))
```